# React Hooks - onClick in generate function

Tags: react-hooks

So I have been creating this "Tree Control" that I want to reuse. This is all working so far.
I might also have missed an existing answer, but perhaps I could not form my search queries properly. It seems like this must has been solved before.

So here is my issue - I have a function that is generating an Array like this:

Notice that I have a "menu" with "Move Up" & "Move Down" onClick's -->

```
    const [ treeData, setTreeData ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        let obj = getData(); //Calling an api here...
        generateTreeStructure(obj);
    }, []);

    const generateTreeStructure = ({ sops, activities }) => {
        let data = [];

        //SOPs
        let sopIndex = 0;
        for (let sop of sops) {
            let newSop = {
                index: sopIndex,
                id: sop.id,
                name: sop.sop_name,
                subItems: [],
                expanded: false,
                menu: [
                    (sopIndex != 0) ? {
                        name: "Move Up", 
                        onClick: () => {
                            let idx = sops.indexOf(sop);
                            //Move up
                            arrayMove(sops, idx, (idx - 1));

                            setTreeData([
                                ...treeData,
                            ]);
                        }
                    } : undefined,
                    (sopIndex != (sops.length - 1)) ? {
                        name: "Move Down", 
                        onClick: () => {
                            let idx = sops.indexOf(sop);
                            //Move down
                            arrayMove(sops, idx, (idx + 1));

                            setTreeData([
                                ...treeData,
                            ]);
                        }
                    } : undefined,
                ],
            };

            data.push(newSop);
            sopIndex++;
        }
        
        setTreeData(data);
    }

    return (
        <TreeControl title="SOP's"
            items={treeData}
        />
    )
```

This ends up generating something like this:
[image]

That menu onClick is an issue... so when I click the button, it seems like React is still looking at the "undefined" value of "treeData", and it will never change it seems.

If I `console.log("treeData", treeData);` it is undefined inside of the generate function. If I add a button inside the "return()" and log it, I see the correct value.

In a way this makes sense to me because at the time the object was generated, that "treeData" was in fact undefined. It's just that --> why won't the onClick see that latest state value?

Now I'm not sure how to get around this... can someone please assist? :) Any help or ideas are very welcome!

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on anything :).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have dependency in your useEffect, meaning `generateTreeStructure` is called once at the component creation (while treeData is undefined)

this should probably solve your issue

```
const [ treeData, setTreeData ] = useState();
const [ data, setData ] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setData(getData()); //Calling an api here...
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    generateTreeStructure(data);
}, [data, treeData])
```

this will call `generateTreeStructure` everytime data or treeData changes

Comment: Great yes this is ALMOST what I need :), but now if it regenerates the Tree, it collapses everything when it updates. 

So if I go and move an item Up or Down, it also collapses all the expanded items again.

Comment: Is `TreeControl` your own code ? It seems to not handle well params update. Assert you have the control on which items are expanded and you don't reset on params update.